# How to use Nikola tag variables out side of tag page

Tags: mako, nikola

I'm working on a Nikola site and want to display tags in a template other than the Tags template. I'm wondering if there is a way without add-ons to get access to the list of tags in the [`items` variable](https://www.getnikola.com/template-variables.html#variables-available-in-the-tags-and-categories-page-tags-tmpl).

```html
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
<%namespace name="helper" file="post_helper.tmpl"/>
<%namespace name="pheader" file="post_header.tmpl"/>
<%namespace name="comments" file="comments_helper.tmpl"/>
<%namespace name="math" file="math_helper.tmpl"/>
<%inherit file="post.tmpl"/>

<%block name="content">
<div class="wordview-header">
  <h1> ${post.title()} </h1>
</div>

${post.text()}

<!-- here I have copied from a tags template the section that generates tags -->
% if items:
<h1>Topics</h1>
    <ul class="list-inline">
    % for text, link in items:
        % if text not in hidden_tags:
            <li><a class="reference badge" href="${link}">${text}</a></li>
        % endif
    % endfor
    </ul>
    % endif

${math.math_scripts_ifpost(post)}
</%block>
```

I'm thinking there is either a way to change it in settings to add the `item` variable to other template files, other than only tags.